# Python: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (school assignment)

Tags: python

I have been having problems with this entire assignment for some reason.

We need to write a program to find the check digit in a UPC code.

I am stumped so here is what I have so far...

```
def Find_UPC():
    upc = str(input("What is the UPC?"))
    odd = upc[0:11:2]
    even = upc[1:12:2]
    oddSum = sum(map(int, odd)) * 3
    evenSum = sum(map(int, even))
    total = oddSum + evenSum
    mod = total % 10
    if mod != 0:
        check = 10 - mod
    else:
        check = mod


    print("Your check didget is: "(check))

Find_UPC()
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/THOR/Desktop/Python/week 4/findUPC.py", line 22, in <module>
Find_UPC()
File "C:/Users/THOR/Desktop/Python/week 4/findUPC.py", line 20, in Find_UPC
print("Your check didget is: "(check))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might change your print with 
print("Your check didget is: %s "  % check)

Comment: `print("Your check didget is:", check)`

Comment: PS digit is spelt "digit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `print` syntax: parentheses are not used to separate values.

Comment: You my friend are a life saver. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print("Your check digit is: " + str(check))
```

Or using function notation:

```
print(f"Your check digit is: {check}")
```

Note the `f` before the quotation marks, and then the variable in curly brackets within the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot the comma. Try:

```
print("Your check didget is: ",check)
```